# Is there an equivalent method in asp.net that behaves exactly as SQL function NCHAR(integer-expression)?

Tags: c#, sql, unicode, encoding, dynamics-crm

I am in process of importing some table values into Microsoft CRM db. During this process, if the text being imported contains certain unicode characters, CRM API fails to import the batch. My goal is to weed out the records that contain these 'illegal' characters.

To that end, I have identified the illegal characters by experimenting on CRM import. I imported each UTF-16, NCHAR(0) - NCHAR(65535), characters and made note of the ones that threw the error.

I now want to create a method in my solution to disallow inputs with the illegal characters. For that, I need to be able to compare each incoming character with the list of illegal characters. My problem is, I am not being able to get the list of illegal characters, such as NCHAR(5) in my solution. Is there a way to convert integer-expressions to UTF-16 character in C# vis-a-vis NCHAR(integer-expression) in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast to `char`. In your example you have `5` and `(char)5` gives you `'\u0005'` just as `NCHAR(5)` does.

(Things are slightly different with the supplementary character flag set, which lets `NCHAR` cover all Unicode characters from 0 to 1114111, which requires a string representation as it can be two UTF-16 units).

Comment: I see. I am printing the first 100 chars to the browser/console and the first 32 of them don't print at all. The ones that actually print match the order that NCHAR(num-ex) prints in SQL. This may have been due to the limitation of the web browser/console in printing certain range of characters. Would this be the correct assumption?

Comment: Do you mean first 32 characters in numerical order from U+0000 (`NCHAR(0)`) to U+0019 (`NCHAR(31)`)? Those are all control characters and while some should have some effect (tab and new line characters should affect output in most cases though in web contexts that'll all merge with the following `NCHAR(32)` into a single space, and some things will still make a sound when you print `NCHAR(7)` which historically rang a bell on a teletype) some have no current use outside specialist cases and won't print as anything. Because some things do still use some such characters for some reasons...

Comment: I'd generally want to know why they were appearing in source code. 9 is tab and commonly used, 13 and 10 for newlines (13 followed by 10 the default in windows, just 10 the default in most other current OSs). Any other in a source would make me really curious as to whether the source intended them to mean something, though my starting suspicion would be that they shouldn't have been in there and something upstream messed up.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_.28ASCII_and_derivatives.29 for a quick description of those codes, and sections 2.13, 23.1 of the Unicode Standard along with the relevant part of the code charts for more.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, Jon. Yes, there were three unexpected characters that showed up in our data, two of them were "illegal" for CRM import. Those UTF-16 values are 10 (new line), 12 (form feed/ new page) , and 24, the latter 2 being illegal. Like I said, I am in the process of filtering all of the "illegal" characters right now. If I find out how these characters ended up in our data, I will be sure to update this thread. Thanks again!